# resize control.size width designer in vb.net winform ,but this action affected other control size

Tags: vb.net, winforms

In designer interface, I drag lblSatus control to resize it. I only want to change the size of the lblstatus control, but this action affected other control, such as lblName control.

```
 Me.lblStatus.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(101, 21)// that is I want

 Me.lblName.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(538, 21) //I do'not hope lblName.size changed
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are accidentally selecting the other label, or maybe selecting both?

Otherwise, I think you should try

```
Label1.Autosize = False
```

Here are 2 samples on ways to change a label's size
(You can Import System.Drawing to make it cleaner)

```
Label1.Size = New Size With {.Width = 50, .Height = 89}
Label1.Size = New Size(50, 89)
```

If that doesnt answer your problem, you might have to explain a little better or whatever is actually causing it not being shown in the explanation at all

Comment: I only selected lblStatus control ,and also I has set Label1.Autosize = False. Your's answer I has been tryed,But it do not work

Comment: Can you provide steps so that I can try to find the problem?
For example
1. Add 2 labels to control in designer window
2. Select 1 control and resize it
etc etc

Comment: I add 3 labels  to control in designer  windows 2,and select 1 control and resize it,and it did not affected other control size.

Comment: You added 3 labels, and you resized one but it did not change the size of the other label right? So your saying to want to change them both at the same time...?

No matter what I do I can not reproduce the problem you described in your original question, the only thing I can think could be wrong is this:
For each of your labels, make sure the Anchor and Dock properties are set to none

Are you able to reproduce the problem if you try to do it again in a new project, or does it only happen in the project you have right now?